"Client attempted a write that is not allowed" MongoDB Atlas Device Realm Flex Sync Database
I am developing an iOS app with Realm and MongoDB Atlas. I never used Atlas before so this is a very interesting learning process. Atlas has a huge learning curve, and i am thankful i figure out everything via Youtube, MongoDB Docs, and ChatGPT.
However, I am encourntering a problem when trying to write a object to realm with database rules on. I set these rules:
{
  "roles": [
    {
      "name": "readAndWriteAll",
      "apply_when": {
        "accountId": "%%user.id"
      },
      "document_filters": {
        "write": true,
        "read": true
      },
      "read": true,
      "write": true,
      "insert": true,
      "delete": true,
      "search": true
    }
  ]
}

With that being said, I am receiving this error when trying to write a new object to the database.
Info: Connection[1] Session[1]: Received: ERROR "Client attempted a write that is not allowed; it has been reverted" (error_code=231, is_fatal=false, error_action=Warning)
I received an error like the before, however, I fixed it with updating my subscription query. I tried basically everything I could think of and the only thing that works is removing the database rules.
Here is my model and RealmManager code
class Venue: Object {
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var _id: String
    @Persisted var accountId: String
    @Persisted var name: String = ""
    @Persisted var location: String = ""
}

@MainActor
func initialize() async throws {
    user = try await app.login(credentials: Credentials.anonymous)

    let configuration = user?.flexibleSyncConfiguration(initialSubscriptions: { subs in
        if subs.first(named: "userAccounts") == nil {
            subs.append(QuerySubscription<UserAccount>(name: "userAccounts"))
        }
        if subs.first(named: "venues") == nil {
            subs.append(QuerySubscription<Venue>(name: "venues"))
        }
    }, rerunOnOpen: true)

    realm = try await Realm(configuration: configuration!, downloadBeforeOpen: .always)
}

@MainActor
func createVenue(name: String, location: String) async throws {
    guard let user = self.user, let account = try await getUserAccountById(), let realm = realm else {
        throw NSError(domain: "RealmManager", code: -1, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "User not logged in"])
    }
    
    let venue = Venue()
    venue._id = UUID().uuidString
    venue.name = name
    venue.accountId = account._id
    venue.location = location
    
    if account._id != "" {
        try realm.write {
            realm.add(venue)
            
            // Link the venue to the user
            if let userObject = realm.object(ofType: UserAccount.self, forPrimaryKey: account._id) {
                userObject.venues.append(venue._id)
                realm.add(userObject, update: .modified)
            }
        }
    }
}


Comment and question: It appears getUserAccountById gets a users account. Why retrieve it again (userObject) within the write? Also, it appears the relationship is hard-coded via the _id string. Why not just have user.venues list as a List of Venue Objects to create a true relationship? Question: can you include the UserAccount and Venue classes in the question so we can see what those models look like? Is it possible this "accountId": "%%user.id" is failing? e.g. the account id is not this uses id? Also, each object can have its own set of rules (roles) - which object are those for?

You may also want to re-name the rule readAndWriteAll as it doesn't read and write all. It only applies to data where the accountId is this users id. If you want it to apply to all data, change that to "apply_when": {},. As is, the filter request will exclude documents that do not have the users id as the value of the accountId. So perhaps the users id does't match?

first thing you need to do is make sure subscriptions are active for useraccount and venue and correctly synced before performing any write operations
look at the sync logs in mongodb Atlas see if there are any additional errors or warnings that provide more context about the permission issue and Make sure if your rule configuration is properly set to allow writes
{
  "roles": [
    {
      "name": "readAndWriteAll",
      "apply_when": {
        "accountId": "%%user.id"
      },
      "document_filters": {
        "write": true,
        "read": true
      },
      "read": true,
      "write": true,
      "insert": true,
      "delete": true,
      "search": true
    }
  ]
}

aslo check if apply_when condition correctly matches the accountId field in your document schema
or maybe you nned to double check your function to create a venue ensure the user has the appropriate permissions and that the accountId matches the condition defined in your rule:
@MainActor
func createVenue(name: String, location: String) async throws {
guard let user = self.user, let account = try await getUserAccountById(), let realm = realm else {
throw NSError(domain: "RealmManager", code: -1, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "User not logged in"])
}
let venue = Venue()
venue._id = UUID().uuidString
venue.name = name
venue.accountId = account._id
venue.location = location

if account._id != "" {
    try realm.write {
        realm.add(venue)

        // Link the venue to the user
        if let userObject = realm.object(ofType: UserAccount.self, forPrimaryKey: account._id) {
            userObject.venues.append(venue._id)
            realm.add(userObject, update: .modified)
        }
    }
}

}

While answers are appreciated, what's in this answer is already in the question; the rules here are the same as in the question, the code in the question adds appropriate rules, the accountId matches the object and the code in the answer is identical to the code in the question. Can you clarify what part of this is an answer? Also, code formatting is important; use the formatting tools {} so it's readable. Note Policy: Generative AI (ChatGPT) is banned Just looking for clarification here.
